# Repositioning Chart Object VBA

Tags: vba, runtime-error, powerpoint

I am trying to create a chart and reposition it afterwards to the correct location on my PowerPoint sheet. But receive a runtime error. The relevant bits of code are:

(My chart data is not in the code)

```
Dim myChart As chart
Dim gChartData As ChartData
Dim gWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim gWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

'Create the chart and set a reference to the chart data.
Set myChart = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.AddChart.chart
Set gChartData = myChart.ChartData

'Set the Workbook and Worksheet references.
Set gWorkBook = gChartData.Workbook
Set gWorkSheet = gWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

    With myChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .ChartStyle = 30
        .ApplyLayout 4
        .ClearToMatchStyle
    End With

    With myChart
        .PlotArea.Left = 290
        .PlotArea.Top = 90
    End With
```

I receive the following error code:

Error: -2147467259 (80004005) during Runtime:

Method Left of object PlotArea failed

Some searching already suggested I may have a macro security problem but in the options all macro actions are currently allowed.

If you need further information please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is moving the chart within the shape that it's been added to, rather than moving the container shape itself.

You need to move the parent of `myChart`:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim myChart As Chart
    Set myChart = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.AddChart.Chart

    With myChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .ChartStyle = 30
        .ApplyLayout 4
        .ClearToMatchStyle

        'Move shape containing chart on PPT.
        With .Parent
            .Left = 290
            .Top = 90
        End With

        'Move chart plot area within chart (I think).
        .PlotArea.Left = 290
        .PlotArea.Top = 90
    End With

End Sub
```

I didn't get the error you have, but that could be trying to move the PlotArea outside the shape?